# JavaScript: clearInterval won't clear interval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, intervals, clearinterval

I have an unusual problem. I'm using the following script to check for internet connection using `navigator.onLine`. If there is internet connection, the page will be refreshed every 15 seconds. If there isn't any internet connection, the page will use `innerHTML` to display a message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function () {
if (navigator.onLine) {
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){window.location.href = "Tracker.html";},15000);
} else {
clearInterval(myInterval);
var changeMe = document.getElementById("change");
change.innerHTML = "<big><font face='Arial' color='#ffffff' size='2'><center>OFFLINE</big><br>No internet connection</font></center>";
}
}, 250);
</script>
```

My problem is, once there is no internet connection, the message will be displayed, BUT the page would still be refreshed one last time. I'm trying to avoid this, by using `clearInterval(myInterval);` in the `else` part of the code, however it won't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [It's not easy to read your code](http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3sdhzo/) `:)`

Comment: Is it necessary to check for a connection before 15s?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas that pic is pure gold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refresh the page at 15 second intervals (provided that a connection is present), use:

```
function refresh() {
    if(navigator.onLine)
        window.location.href = "Tracker.html";
    else{
        var changeMe = document.getElementById("change");
        change.innerHTML = "<big><font face='Arial' color='#ffffff' size='2'><center>OFFLINE</big><br>No internet connection</font></center>";
        setTimeout(refresh, 250);
    }
}
setTimeout(refresh, 15000);
```

At the end of 15 seconds, this checks whether a connection is present. If there is, it refreshes the page. If there isn't, it proceeds to check every 250 milliseconds afterwards until the user is reconnected, at which point it refreshes the page.

The net result is that the script refreshes the page as soon as possible after a minimum of 15 seconds have elapsed.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/JGEt9/show

Comment: But the OP want's to continuously test whether there is a connection or not. If there is no connection, a message should be shown. Once there is a connection again, the "reload timeout" should start again/continue. Your's just waits for 15 seconds and if the there is no connection, it just stops.

Comment: @FelixKling This refreshes the page after 15 seconds if a connection is present. If no connection is present, the page is not refreshed.

Comment: Yes... but what if there is a connection again? Or is your answer in addition to the OP's other code?

Comment: @FelixKling Right, but the clearInterval is supposed to "just stop" as well, if there is no connection present. No further action is supposed to take place except the DOM manipulation.

Comment: The `clearInterval` was supposed to stop the reloading, not the connection testing. Once a connection exist again, the reload should continue.

Comment: @FelixKling I've updated my answer. I think this makes more sense than what the OP was doing, because essentially right now the OP is looking for an unbroken spell of connected statuses. If the connection is interrupted for only 250 ms every 15 seconds, the page will never refresh.

Comment: I found an issue with this solution. setTimeout(refresh, 250) is being ignored. It's never being used.

Comment: @EliUnger Select Work Offline from the your browser menu. After 15 seconds, the `OFFLINE` message should show up. At this point the 250 ms timeout kicks in. It checks every 250 ms if the connection has been restored, and if it has, it refreshes the page.

Comment: @EliUnger Are you seeing behavior that is inconsistent with this?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the outer interval callback is executed, a new `myInterval` variable is created and the previous one is lost (it goes out of scope because the callback terminates).

You have to persist the value of the variable between function calls by declaring it outside of the function. You also have to make sure that you are not creating another timeout if one is already running.

```
var timeout = null;

setInterval(function () {
    if (navigator.onLine) {
        if (timeout === null) {
            timeout = setInterval(function(){window.location.href = "Tracker.html";},15000);
        }
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
        // ...
   }
}, 250);
```

Comment: The value will still not be persisted, since the page is being refreshed.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem... if the page refreshes, there obviously was a connection and the test is just started again.

Comment: I already had a stupid smile on my face, thinking my problem was solved 'so easily' after hours of research. But no, it won't work :(

Comment: And why? What's the problem? "won't work" is not a helpful error description.

Comment: Meaning, there's one last refresh, like before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `myInterval` outside of the if statement. You should only need the refresh code once too. Something like this:

```
var myInterval = setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = "Tracker.html";},15000);
setInterval(function () {
  if (!navigator.onLine) {
    clearTimeout(myInterval);
    var changeMe = document.getElementById("change");
    changeMe.innerHTML = "<big><font face='Arial' color='#ffffff' size='2'><center>OFFLINE</big><br>No internet connection</font></center>";
  }
}, 250);
```

Here you set the refresh interval and continually check to see if the browser is offline, and if it is, you remove the timer and do your cleanup code. I also changed the refresh code to use setTimeout instead of interval because it only happens once.

Another issue is you create `changeMe` but then try to use `change`. `change` doesn't exist. I fixed that in my example as well.

**Note:** This will *not* resume refreshing once connection is regained. See Felix Kling's answer.

Comment: But then the page will be refreshed regardless of the IF condition being true or false.

Comment: @EliUnger it won't because the offline check happens more frequently than the refresh.

Comment: `clearInterval(myInterval);` should be `clearTimeout(myInterval);`.

Comment: But I want to resume refreshing once connection is regained. That's the whole point.

Comment: @EliUnger see my note at the end, Felix Kling has exactly that.